# How use other written methods with present method

Tags: java

I wrote a program for this problem:
“Write a program that, given an array array[] of n numbers and another number x, determines whether or not there exist two elements in array whose sum is exactly x.”

Which is this:

```
boolean hasArrayTwoCandidates (int array[], int sum) {

    int length = array.length;

    quickSort(array, 0, length-1);

    int first, last;
    first = 0;
    last = length-1; 

    while(first < last){

         if( array[first] + array[last] == sum )
              return true; 
         else if( array[first] + array[last] < sum )
              first++;
         else // array[i] + array[j] > sum
              last--;
    }    
    return false;
}
```

At first place, I don't know where should I put or add "quick sort" codes.  I have this problem with other programs, as well; when I want to add written methods to the present one.

1. Should I create a "new class" under this "project" and put "quicksort" codes there?
2. Should I put them in this class? but how can I use it?

At second place, I don't know what should I write in my "main method"?

this is my quicksort codes:

```
public void sort(int[] values) {

  if (values == null || values.length == 0){
    return;
  }

  this.array = values;
  length = values.length;
  quickSort(this.array, 0, length - 1);
}


private void quickSort(int[] array, int low, int high) {

  int i = low, j = high;
  int pivot = array[low + (high-low)/2];

    while (i <= j) {                

    while (array[i] < pivot) {
      i++;
    }       

    while (array[j] > pivot) {
      j--;
    }   

    if (i <= j) {
      exchange(i, j);
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  }

  if (low < j)
    quickSort(array, low, j);
  if (i < high)
    quickSort(array, i, high);
}    

private void exchange(int i, int j) {
  int temp = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = temp;
}
```

actually, I dont know what should I write in my "main method" to run this program?

Comment: do you think sort is necessary?

Comment: @Baby, I am not sure; but if we don't use "sort", how we can detect those two numbers?

Comment: you can sum up all the possible pair without sorting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For you Question you can do simply this kind of coding in main method:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
        int x = 20;
        int[] arr = {2,5,4,10,12,5};
        System.out.println(hasArrayTwoCandidates(arr,x));

    }
```

make the methods `static`

```
static boolean hasArrayTwoCandidates (int array[], int sum)
```

But there are porblems in your coding:

```
private void exchange(int i, int j) {
  int temp = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = temp;
}
```

Here the array is not defined. you'll get an error. you have to pass the array too to the method make it as.

```
private void exchange(int i, int j,int[] array)
```

But since you are not necessary to do sorting. I recommend this.

```
static boolean hasArrayTwoCandidates (int array[], int sum) {
        boolean flag = false;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<array.length ;j++){
            if(array[i]+array[j] == sum)
                flag = true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

this will get one element and check while adding other elements that it is `true` 
Then the main method come same way.

Comment: thank you for your solution. but it seems it only sum "two consecutive numbers" together. what if the sum is: array[0] + array[5]?

Comment: @Hengameh there are two loops. one select the first number and other one iterate through the rest. So array[0] + array[5] gets covered.

Comment: change your arr[] in different ways and check. :)

Comment: why did you put " i < array.length-1 " and not " i < array.length" ?

Comment: and last question: time complexity of your proposed solution is O(n^2), right?

Comment: Thats because the second loop starts with `i` lets say the array is 5 elements long. The final thing you want to check is element 4 + element 5. So the i loop will iterate for  array.length-1

Comment: for the last Question . Yes since there are 2 for loops

Comment: for this:  " i < array.length-1 " or " i < array.length" ? I think since you already put "<" instead of "<=", so no need to "-1", right?

Comment: Hmm, yes you can. I just checked to make sure and yes it works.

Comment: And regarding no need to use "Sorting", I used sort to decrease time complexity. since if we use sorting (merge sort or heap sort), time complexity will be O(nlgn) [for quicksort, also average case is O(nlgn)]; but if we go through the array and sum them up, time complexity will be O(n^2).

Comment: For both Questions yes. Given the requirements and other facts thought of this answer. Since you haven't mention about the set of data using in the array and the consideration on the time complexity never thought of them.

Comment: If you want to carry on with your answer the answer is in the first part :)

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to mention pros and cons. and you are right, basically there is no condition :) I made them up!

Answer (score 4):

you can put all those method in same class, make `hasArrayTwoCandidates()` `static` (Note that main method is static and a static method can have access only to static methods)

```
public static boolean hasArrayTwoCandidates (int array[], int sum) {
    ....
}
```

and in your main method you can test it like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] arr = {2,5,12,5,2,7,15};
    System.out.print(hasArrayTwoCandidates(arr, 27));
}
```

Comment: You mean all those method should be "static"? Could you please tell me why?

Comment: because main method is static and a static method can have access only to static methods

Comment: not all methods, but only method that you call directly from main method

Answer (score 1):

Answering your questions: you can write methods and call them within the same class, just write them with the static modifier:

```
    private static <return_type> <methodName> (<type> param1, <type> param2) {
            // Your code here
    }
```

For a program like this, I don't get why you are thinking about sorting the array before checking the sum of 2 numbers within it, when you could do all at once. Check out this code, this may shine a light on you. It is straight-forward and only to see if it clarifies your logic.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class VerifySum {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[10];

    // Produce a random number from 10 to 20
    int randomSum = rand.nextInt(11) + 10;

    // Fill out the array with random integers from 0 to 10
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = rand.nextInt(11);
    }

    // Check all array indexes against each other
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] + array[j] == randomSum) {
                System.out.println(array[i] + " + " + array[j] + " = " + randomSum);
            }
        }
    }

    // Print "x"
    System.out.println("randomSum = " + randomSum);

    // Print array for verification of the functionality
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("array [" + i + "] = " + array[i]);
    }


}

}
```

Sometimes making it simpler is more efficient. ;-)

Comment: if we use sorting (merge sort or heap sort), time complexity will be O(nlgn) [for quicksort, also average case is O(nlgn)]; but if we go through the array and sum them up, time complexity will be O(n^2). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right! Then you can simply add a break into the loop, so as soon as it finds the 2 numbers which the sum is equal to your "x", the loop breaks. The O you mentioned is valid for the sorting algorithm only, but if you add complexity to it, by looking for the numbers within the array for example, your code won't be as efficient as the sorting O you targeted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. you mean this is not correct?   **O(n)+O(nlogn) = O(nlogn)**?

Comment: Hi @Hengameh. No, I didn't mean that. I think that's is correct, not sure.